# GitHub-Permission denied when pushing

Tags: macos, github, permission-denied

I am new to github and I have some troubles when pushing repository to github. I am working on Mac Lion. I followed all steps to set up public and private key pair.

Then I ran

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

and I can receive

```
"Hi SKSC! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."
```

Till now, everything seems correct

Then I launched `GitHub.app` for Mac and then went to `My Repository/RepositoryName/Branches` and click `public` button. I got "Permission denied(PublicKey)" error.

However, I can clone repository to computer, no error at all.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> ssh -T git@github.com
>
> and I can receive
>
> "Hi SKSC! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access."

This public key setup step is for command-line access.

Using GitHub For Mac, you need to setup your account in the `Preferences` in Mac menu by typing in your e-mail and password. It will automatically add public key in your account

Also you can check https://github.com/account/ssh. If GitHub for Mac is setup correctly, you can see a public key named `GitHub for Mac - your-computer-name`

I think you can clone because github is public for cloning for everyone. Pushing needs to verify your credential. So GitHub for Mac didn't get configured correct probably.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I should first create a new online repo in github.com and then push local repo. I expected GitHub to create online repo automatically, it seems I can wrong. Thank you.